# Testng. How to handle this exception correctly

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have the method which calculates angles of the triangle when all sides are known:

```
public static double[] calculateTriangleAngles(double a, double b, double c) {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0 || a >= b + c || b >= a + c || c >= a + b) {
        throw new TriangleTechnicalException("Incorrect side value");
    }
    double[] angles = new double[3];
    angles[0] = round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((pow(b, 2) + pow(c, 2) - pow(a, 2)) / (2 * b * c))), 2);
    angles[1] = round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((pow(a, 2) + pow(c, 2) - pow(b, 2)) / (2 * a * c))), 2);
    angles[2] = round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2) - pow(c, 2)) / (2 * a * b))), 2);
    return angles;
}
```

Calculation algorithm is correct. Question about exception. It must be thrown here.

How can I handle this exception correctly (use `throws` or `try`/`catch` right here or something else?)? Or maybe better throws it (but this method can look not correctly, surrounded `try`/`catch` in tests)?

```
@Test
public void testCalculateTriangleAnglesTrue() {
    double[] expResult = {48.19, 58.41, 73.4};
    double[] result = new double[3];
    try {
        result = TriangleFunctional.calculateTriangleAngles(7, 8, 9);
    } catch (TriangleTechnicalException e) {
        fail();
    }
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expResult, result));
}
```

Can you help me with this question?

Comment: Declare it with `throws TriangleTechnicalException`. When calling the method, either handle it with `try`/`catch` **if you can do so meaningfully**, or if you can't, just add `throws TriangleTechnicalException` to that method too. Only `catch` exceptions when you know how to deal with them (whether that means retry, log a warning, abort the program, whatever).

Comment: That depends... How do you *want* this method to behave under these conditions.  Do you *want* it to throw an exception?  Or something else?  How do you *want* consuming code to handle it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I'd like to handle this exception in method which has this method - `calculateTriangleAngles`. When I'll use `throws` with method `calculateTriangleAngles`, it will be not great for testing this method, I think. 
`try`/`catch` in tests are good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add throws to your method declaration.

```
public static double[] calculateTriangleAngles(double a, double b, double c) throws TriangleTechnicalException {
```

Then whenever you use this method, you need to either do so inside of a try block, or have that method also throw the TriangleTechnicalException

Comment: It's understandable, thanks. But question about tests. Can I use try/catch in tests? If not, how can I solve this problem by another way?

Comment: Or I can throw it through test using `public void testCalculateTriangleAnglesTrue() throws TriangleTechnicalException`?

Comment: You can use the try/catch in the test.  Are you having an issue doing this?  I would put a fail() in the catch in your example because it doesn't look like it should throw the exception.  If you want to test that the exception is being thrown correctly, put a fail after a call to calculateTriangleAngles with invalid sides.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to declare that `calculateTriangleAngles` throws `TriangleTechnicalException`, i.e. change first line to

```
public static double[] calculateTriangleAngles(double a, double b, double c) 
    throws TriangleTechnicalException {
```

so that the caller is informed that there is a problem. This is, I believe, much better than handling the error within the method and returning some kind of special value or (even worse) a value which assumes values to resolve the error or something like that.

If I remember correctly, if `TriangleTechnicalException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException` then callers don't have to catch the exception; if the exception occurs, it will bubble up until some caller catches it, or it reaches the top level and the program terminates. So test cases need not catch the exception. But you will certainly want to test the error-handling code, in which case you will want to catch the exception, to verify that the error handling works as expected.